# Get likes from Facebook post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook post ID like:`19292868552_10150189643478553`;
When I put it to Graph API Explorer, it returns normal output, but if i use code like:

```
function testo(){
    FB.api('/19292868552_10150189643478553/likes',function(response){
      if(response.data){
        console.log(response.data);
      }else{
        alert('error');
      }
    })
 }
```

It returns nothing. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on JSFiddle and it worked fine. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdnmU/1/).

You should make sure the Facebook JS file is loaded and initalized before you're making the call to the

```
FB.api('/19292868552_10150189643478553/likes',function(response)...
```

function. You are probably making the call too early.

Comment: It doesn't work on JSFiddle for me, but that doesn't matter. Maybe i need access token? How get and use it with that code?

Comment: I don't get how the fiddle works for me and not for you. Can you try it on some other browser?